# Fontawesome 5 error

Tags: fontawesome

I am using the latest `fontawesome` package for latex version 5.9.0 and it seems that not all icons are usable. In thw following MWE `\faIcon{phone-alt}` says it is not found.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\faIcon{phone}
\faIcon{phone-alt}
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following error

```
fontawesome5 error: "icon-not-found" The requested icon phone-alt was not found. For immediate help type H <return>.
```

**EDIT**
This is the last part of my log file.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontawesome5.sty    2019/03/20 v5.8.0 Font Awesome 5
   expl3.sty    2018-06-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018-06-14 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
l3keys2e.sty    2018-05-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  xparse.sty    2018-05-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty    2019/03/20 v5.8.0 uTeX helper for fontawesome5
tufontawesomefree.fd
tufontawesomebrands.fd
 ***********
```

Indeed I was **not** using version 5.9.0 as I thought but 5.8.0. I updated the package and everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems you do **not** use version 5.9 of `fontawesome5` ...

I could reproduce your error with using the older version 5.8.  After updating my MiKTeX I got the new version 5.9: `fontawesome5.sty    2019/06/07 v5.9.0 Font Awesome 5`.

Please run the following mwe (I added command `\listfiles` to get a list of all used packages and version numbers)

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\faIcon{phone} and 
\faPhone or 
\faPhone* or 
\faIcon{phone-alt}
\end{document}
```

and got the following list of used packages (check your `log` file for it. You should find the list at the end of the file. You need this command only for this testing purpose!):

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontawesome5.sty    2019/06/07 v5.9.0 Font Awesome 5
   expl3.sty    2019-05-28 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-05-28 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2019-05-28 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  xparse.sty    2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontawesome5-generic-helper.sty    2019/06/07 v5.9.0 non-uTeX helper for fontawesome5
fontawesome5-mapping.def
ufontawesomefree0.fd
ufontawesomefree3.fd
 ***********
```

compiling without error and the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please copy my code, run it on your computer and check the log file for the used version of `fontawesome5`. If it really lists version 5.9 then please add the complete log file for my code to your question ...

Comment: I added the log file to my question and of course you were right. The problem is solved with the latest update.